# Unable to deploy war file to weblogic 12c

Tags: deployment, war, weblogic12c

When I try to 'Activate' my newly deployed .WAR file on the weblogic - I get an error in the AdminServer log file.

[image: enter image descr[![enter image description here]iption here][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9iVA4.png)][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9iVA4.png)

> weblogic.management.DeploymentException: **Exception occured while
>   downloading files**
>                   at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.datamanagement.AppDataUpdate.doDownload(AppDataUpdate.java:49)
>                   at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.datamanagement.DataUpdate.download(DataUpdate.java:57)
>                   at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.datamanagement.Data.prepareDataUpdate(Data.java:117)
>                   at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.BasicDeployment.prepareDataUpdate(BasicDeployment.java:750)
>                   at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.prepareDataUpdate(AbstractOperation.java:918)
>                   Caused By:
>   **java.io.IOException: There is not enough space on the disk**
>                   at java.io.FileOutputStream.writeBytes(Native Method)
>                   at java.io.FileOutputStream.write(FileOutputStream.java:326)
>                   at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
>                   at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.write(BufferedOutputStream.java:121)

There is lots of space on the E drive where weblogic and application resides. I tried to move the log files out of tmp and restarted one of the instance(there are 2 instances-load balanced) and didn't work.

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I should have checked the both Servers on which my application runs. The A10P002 server disk was out of space. I just deleted old .Log files and server is back to normal and I am able to deploy - **No more** 'java.io.IOException'.

[image]